# Cannot connect to wired ethernet after hibernate

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

When I am at home I use wired connection on my laptop and it works fine. Then I put it to hibernate with `sudo pm-hibernate` and start it up again when I am work. I am not able to connect to internet without a reboot of the machine.

I have tried:

```
 ifconfig eth0 down
 ifconfig eth0 up
```

But it does not help. Also:

```
 dhclient eth0
```

This took a long time to run and when finished still no success.  Found this in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 15 08:22:38 frank dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x4183b95d)
Jul 15 08:22:45 frank dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x4183b95d)
Jul 15 08:22:53 frank dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x4183b95d)
Jul 15 08:23:03 frank dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x4183b95d)
Jul 15 08:23:18 frank dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x4183b95d)
Jul 15 08:23:29 frank dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16 (xid=0x4183b95d)
Jul 15 08:25:33 frank avahi-autoipd(eth0)[5647]: Callout STOP, address 167.198.2.6 on interface eth0
Jul 15 08:25:33 frank avahi-autoipd(eth0)[5648]: client: RTNETLINK answers: No such process
Jul 15 08:25:33 frank avahi-autoipd(eth0)[5648]: client: RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
Jul 15 08:25:33 frank avahi-autoipd(eth0)[5648]: Script execution failed with return value 2
Jul 15 08:26:59 frank NetworkManager[949]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Jul 15 08:26:59 frank NetworkManager[949]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jul 15 08:26:59 frank NetworkManager[949]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jul 15 08:26:59 frank NetworkManager[949]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

Exact same thing happens when I put the laptop to hibernate at work and start it up again at home. Anyone got a clue to why I have to reboot to make wired connection work after hibernate?

I am using `Mint 17` with the latest updates.

Comment: What happens if you `ifconfig eth0 down` **before** you hibernate, then hibernate, then `ifconfig eth0 up` **after** you start it up ?

Comment: @Lawrence Not sure, I have to try this. I will try it today before I leave work and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215738/130279) one of the root cause would be the misconfiguration of NetworkManager. Re-installation of NetworkManager might help.

Also please watch out that you may be out of connection during re-installation.

Another option would be to replace `NetworkManager` with `wicd`.

Comment: It sounds strange to have to do it every twice a day.

Comment: @user11498 you can try replacing `NetworkManager` with `wicd`